# PC Case Side loudly vibrating when on high fan RPM

Tags: cpu, fan, noise, case

My CPU is an AMD FX-6300 and it is cooled by it's stock cooler. The problem with the stock is that it tends to spin at 6600+ RPM when on heavy load. So every time I start GTA V for example I start hearing that high buzzing noise and it makes the sound much louder than it's supposed to be. I noticed that the fan is probably oscillating at a frequency close to the rear side panel of the case's natural frequency and as a result the panel starts vibrating unnecessarily loud. (I know this because whenever I touch the vibrating side panel of the case the loud vibration stops until I stop applying pressure to it). Any kind people to suggest a quick solution to the problem? :)

Comment: You could put a "stiffener" on the panel to stop it vibrating

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stiffener"?

Comment: You glue a thin metal/or plastic strip diagonally across the panel.

Comment: There are also special products you can buy [3M™ Vibration/Sound Damping Products](http://products3.3m.com/catalog/au/en005/manufacturing_industry/specialty_tapes/node_GSY86NB39Xbe/root_D58K9TX3VWgv/vroot_QZ630XWWPPge/gvel_VGHQM42SJKgl/theme_au_specialtytapes_3_0/command_AbcPageHandler/output_html)

Comment: Duct tape might be enough to to stop it.

Comment: Thank you for the smart suggestions. I'll try duct tape tomorrow and if that doesn't work I'll consider another viable store bought solution or something. Thanks for taking the time to answer dude! Have a great day! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick, zero cost, solution would be using a program like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) to slightly modify/control the RPM of either fan if you're sure the problem is that the natural frequencies are the same.

Comment: Check fan for dust bunnies. An uneven accumulation can throw off dynamic balance.

Comment: I'll try that and I'll let you know. Thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: I guess the panel is just vibrating as a whole... It kinda stops below 6000 RPM but I guess the problem is not quite because it's resonating at near frequencies. Seems like the panel is kind of loose. Problem is I can't figure out a way to stiffen it up. :(